# The definition of open set in metric space and general topological zpace

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The definition of open set is different in metric space and topological space, though metric space is a special case of topological space. The definition in metric space seems to convey the idea that all the points isolated from outside from outside, while the definition in topological space is intended to separate different points, so I don't know how to link them.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In a topological space, there is no definition of open set that I know of. Rather the open sets are given, and assumed to satisfy certain axioms (that are indeed satisfied by the open sets in metric space).

Answer (score 1):

A metric space has a metric function which can be used to define the notion of open set. Thus, in a metric space the notion of open space is derived from the metric. In a topological space the open sets are not derived from anything, they are given axiomatically. The axioms for a topology are chosen to capture some of the properties of the open sets in a metric space. It is incorrect to say that the definition in a topological space is intended to separate different points, nor that in a metric space the intention is to isolate points.

Metric spaces and topological spaces can actually be seen to coincide if in the definition of metric space you take a more general lattice for the values of the metric than the lattice $[0,\infty ]$. It is then the case that every topological space is metrizable, so the open sets of any topology are derived from a suitable metric as in the usual case. More concretely, the category of all such metric spaces and continuous mappings is equivalent (but not isomorphic) to the category of all topological spaces. That means that the two things are just different models for the same concept of topology.

Comment: Could u be more concrete for general metric for topological space

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4940 (published in Algebra Universalis).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a *topology* $\mathcal{T}$ on a set $X$ is given as follows: Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following:

1. Both the empty set and $X$ itself belong to $\mathcal{T}$.
2. The union of any collection of subsets $\{U_\alpha \; | \; \alpha \in I\}$ of $\mathcal{T}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$, namely $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}$.
3. The intersection of any finite collection $\{U_1, \ldots, U_n\}$ of sets in $\mathcal{T}$ is contained in $\mathcal{T}$, or rather $\bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k \in \mathcal{T}$.

Once we have a collection $\mathcal{T}$ defined like this for a set $X$, we *define the elements of $\mathcal{T}$ to be open in $X$.*  You may have seen in your analysis class that open sets in a metric space satisfy the above three conditions, but in general topological spaces don't need to have a metric associated with them.  The simplest example of how a metric can't be attached to all topological spaces is the indiscrete topology: For any set $X$ define a topology $\mathcal{T} =\{\emptyset, X\}$.  The idea that you mentioned about separating points is not true for all topological spaces since the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, X\}$ cannot separate any of the points of $X$.

Comment: With just a slight generalization of the axioms of a metric space every topological space is metrizable.